# How to get notified when a window get focus in WPF?

Tags: wpf, focus

I want to get notified when I click a window in WPF (I use the GotFocus event), but it only triggers when I click on a Combobox in the window. What I want is to get notified when the the window or any of the controls in the window is clicked. Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28VS.85%29.aspx) event doesn't get fired when the Window gets focus, it's intended to be used with controls only. The [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated%28VS.85%29.aspx) event serves this particular purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Use Activated event instead of GotFocus.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged` event. It should trigger when the keyboard focus is taken by an element of the window, or when it is taken by another window