# MVVM/WPF - Always show combobox drop down list when user is typing in the text box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to force the drop down to open when the user is typing in the text box.

I have logic in place to filter the list and when i do not bind anything to the IsDropDownOpen element, it seems to work as desired, except if the textbox loses focus, and then refocused, the dropdown wont come back unless i click the arrow.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="nodeList" 
    Text="{Binding UserInput, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding NodeTokenList}" DisplayMemberPath="FullNodeName" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" 
    Margin="162,49,0,0" Height="32" 
    IsDropDownOpen="{Binding Path=ShowDropDown, Mode=TwoWay, Converter= {StaticResource BoolToVis}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Above is my xaml.

Everytime UserInput is changed (the item source for the text), it filters the itemsource for the drop down list. I now have it so that ShowDropDown (my bool for the IsDropDownOpen)

Here is my UserInput and ShowDropDown definition:

```
public string UserInput
{
     get { return _userInput; }
     set
         {
           _userInput = value;
           FilterListOnKeyPress();
           OnPropertyChanged("UserInput");                              
         }
}

public bool ShowDropDown
{
     get { return _showDropDown; }
     set
         {
           _showDropDown = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ShowDropDown");
         }
}
```

and finally here is my implementation of FilterListOnKeyPress()

```
private void FilterListOnKeyPress()
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInput))
     {
         NodeTokenList = BackUpNodeTokenList;
         return;
     }
     else
     {
         NodeTokenList = BackUpNodeTokenList.Where(x => x.FullNodeName.ToLower().Contains(UserInput.ToLower())).ToList();
                ShowDropDown = true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if an AutoCompleteBox might be a better option in this case.

Comment: You'd probably need to handle the GetFocus explicitly, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217268/how-to-get-notified-when-a-window-get-focus-in-wpf

Comment: `ShowDropDown` isn't mvvm.  And MVVM doesn't mean "no codebehind".  Showing the user a dropdown is a UI function.  Handle the logic in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an observation but IsDropDownOpen is a boolean property and it looks as though you are using a BoolToVisibility converter on it.